# how to browse a vhost on dev server without updating hosts

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

With apache 2 the vhosts works fine if I update the hosts file.  Is there a url that others can use to get to the vhost without having to update their hosts file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to setup a dns server as Gerry suggests you could simply use different ports  instead of referring to them by name

Comment: Both yours and Pikkarainen are great methods. I should have figured out the ports thingy myself.  Your idea works best for me because I do not have to do any tweaks to other computers.  Thanks much!

Comment: Yeah or upgrade your network to IPv6 and use IPs =D

Answer (score 1):

You can register a domain that points to the IP of your server. Then in the vhost config you set that domain as an alias for the vhost.

Or if you already own a domain you can point one of it's subdomains at that server and again add it as an alias in the vhost config.

Oh and another option would be to set up your own DNS server and get them to use it, but that might be a little more work than you are wanting. In the long run it's a lot more flexible and easy to manage. But it can be quite a challenge the first time.

Comment: This is just an inhouse dev server in a small office. We want marketing to see it without having to fiddle with their hosts file.  Since we have many vhosts running we can't just make it off the apache root.

Comment: Yeah I've managed a setup just like that in the past. Your best option in the long term is to set up a DNS server and then set that as main dns server in the office router that everybody uses (either that or set the dns manually on each of their systems).

Answer (score 1):

I use [Modify Headers](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/modify-headers/) Firefox extension and just modify the `Host` header with it as necessary.

For example, if your development server is `dev.www.yoursite.com` and you need to request `mycoolgizmo.com` from it, just set Modify Headers to send `mycoolgizmo.com` Host header when browsing to `dev.www.yoursite.com`.